# change domain name for app deployed with meteor up onto aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, dns

I've deployed my meteor app on an aws EC2 instance, and I can successfully access the app through the public DNS amazon provides. Now I want the app on a domain that I bought.

I thought I could do this by changing root url in my mup.json: `"ROOT_URL": "http://www.example.org"`.

I then tried running `mup reconfig` and `mup deploy`. Both ran successfully, but when I go to http://www.example.org, nothing is there. More specifically, chrome tells me:

> The server at www.example.org can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS >is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. >This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a >misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a >firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

What am I missing here? I bought the domain through google domains if that's relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up an A record through Google Domains to point to the public facing ip address of your ec2 server?

Comment: yes i did. I made a "Custom resource record", type A, with the public facing ip address.  I also made a "Registered host" with the ip, although I left the "IPV6 ADDRESS" blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple pieces of the puzzle that you need to understand.  First, you need an DNS A record to point to the IP address to which the domain should resolve.  In order to configure this in your DNS (which oftentimes is also managed with your domain registrar), you will actually need an IP address to point to.  The thing you need to understand about EC2 instances is that the public-facing IP address for your instance is not dependable.  If you ever terminate/restart your instance it will change.  To solve this problem, AWS offers elastic IP addresses.  The elastic IP provides you with a stable IP address that you can attach to an EC2 instance to have a consistent way of routing requests to your instance(s) running your sites.

An elastic IP can however only be attached to a single instance, so if you ever wanted to run your website across multiple instances (to balance load for example), then you would need to look at using an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) as the target for your DNS record.  The ELB will allow you to attach multiple instances to it in order to spread the load across the attached instances.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I plan on setting up an elastic ip later, but for now I just wanted to get the site up. I believe I've made a DNA A record to point to the IP address--- I added a "Custom resource record", type a, with the ip address.

Comment: I later realized the above answer was the answer to my issue, but it takes a while (~24 hours) for this record to be updated